# Twilio test credentials don't work

Tags: ruby, twilio

I'm trying to send a text message with Twilio like this:

```
@client.account.messages.create(
  from: '+15005555006',
  to: '+15555555555',
  body: 'Hey there!'
)
```

and I get the following error:

> Twilio::REST::RequestError: The From phone number +15005555006 is not
>   a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your
>   account.

This is odd to me because according to [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages-parameters-From), +15005550006 is the one and only valid number when you're using your test credentials.

FWIW, my production creds work just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, they're pretty close. Doesn't that count for anything?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number should be `+15005550006` per the docs you cited. You've got `5006` as the last four digits instead of `0006`.

Comment: Ha! You're right. So evidently the docs are just wrong? (BTW I'll accept your answer after the delay SO requires.)

Comment: Nope. See clarified answer.

Comment: Ah. I copied the number from this erroneous forum post: http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/problem_sending_sms_with_test_credentials. (Linking in case anyone else wants to screw up their own day.)

Comment: That's frustrating. I just added a couple of comments on that thread in the hopes others won't end up wasting their time.